# Get value in one column depending on values in two other columns

Tags: google-sheets

Hy,
I have a sheet with 3 columns.

```
A = date
B = number
C = number
```

I need to automate input of the date, so when you put a number in B or C, in A to insert date.  If B is not blank and C is blank insert date , and vice versa.

So I tried various formulas but when I make now() all dates yearlier will be modified to current.

Current working formula is `=IF(B7<>"";IF(A7<>"";A7;NOW());"")` but I cannot sort this out to check in C.

Comment: To clarify, do you want column A to be the date on which cells B or C in the row are populated?  So if I fill in cell C3 on January 5, A3 reads 1/5/2017 and filling in cell B5 on January 8 results in A5 reading 1/8/2017, without impacting previous rows?

Comment: Yes, without impacting previous rows. B and C will be the some currencies, so I have to sum them along the way but input of data will not be everyday. (Sorry about my caracter formating, I’m on phone)

Comment: I tried : =IF(OR(B3<>""; C3<>"");NOW();"") but the previous inputs are messed up by data.

Answer (score 1):

The formula approach won't work since it will always recalculate using NOW().

In order to accomplish the automatic date assignments in your date column such that they are not replaced every time with real-time dates/timestamps, you need a "timestamp" script that saves the date in column A without depending on a formula in column A. Unfortunately, this will require user interaction to populate the column, but still saves keystrokes of typing in the date/timestamp.

Check out this script: 
https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0Nqqz9c5L-KM?hl=en

Depending on your experience writing scripts/macros in Google Sheets, you could add another custom script that detects content being added/edited in columns B or C and then fires the timestamp script in the respective row's column A.

Comment: Thanks Anson but I tried scritpting and is a problem, sheets that I am using is online, from docs.google.com so I cannot run scripts because the app/script needs to be verified from google. Try the first formula, its always working.